# How to transmit TV's audio out as 802.11 WiFi to cell phone's WiFi, without using the cell phone's Bluetooth?

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth-audio, router, smart-tv

I would like to stream the TV's audio signal via 802.11 WiFi, (not Bluetooth). This way, my cellphone's Bluetooth is available for the Bluetooth headset.

I have a multipoint headset, but the cellphone only functions correctly by automatically reducing the music-audio, when it receives the music-audio signal via WiFi. When I use the headphone's extra Bluetooth multipoint, connected to the TV, via an "audio to Bluetooth transmitter", the headset will not reduce the TV's sound when a call comes in, and upon answering the call, the multipoint-TV connection is lost. However, when listening to music from the internet via the cellphone's WiFi, the phone and headset perform perfectly.

Is there a way to perhaps, send the TV's audio out through an actual WiFi router to the cellphone, just as though it came from the internet?